# 401 unauthorized laravel 5.4 passport + vuejs2 SPA + localhost xampp

Tags: apache, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, axios

i'm creating spa with vuejs 2 using laravel passport with the same tutorial like in [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) and there is something weird happening, i first using this api route for my api calls from vue using axios

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/get_artikel', 'ArtikelController@get_artikel');
```

and it works fine. But when i change it to this

```
Route::resource('artikel', 'ArtikelController');
```

and add __construct into ArtikelController for auth

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

its return 401 unathorized, even thought when i open inspector in chrome and in application tab i see laravel_token, laravel_session and XSRF-TOKEN in there.

so what is happening here? i do some searching and everybody say it works fine in ngix server and there is no working solution for apache server (i have tried all of it)

for the auth, passport and everything else i follow laravel documentation.

Comment: At least in your example, the two routes are different. The get route above points to "/get_artikel" and  the resource route url points to "/artikel".

Comment: yes because in resource route it containt public function index that has the same code as /get_artikel function, it just make more sense using resource then add one by one route